# I would like to update table using merge and my table source will use cross join

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge, cross-join

I have a Table1:

```
IdT1 : 11, 12, 13

IdT1Group : 30,30,30
```

Table2:

```
IdT2 : 1, 2, 3, 4

IdT1 : 11, 11, 12, 12

Detail : A, B, A, B
```

AND User Defined Table Type @T2:

```
IdT2 : 1, 2, 3

IdT1 : 11,11,11

Detail: A,B,C
```

I would like to Update Table2 to be:

```
IdT2 : 1,2,5, 3,4,6, 7,8,9

IdT1 : 11,11,11, 12,12,12, 13,13,13

Detail : A,B,C, A,B,C, A,B,C
```

So, I was Use Merge in StoredProcedure:

```
;WITH Table2
    AS (SELECT Table2.* FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.IdT1 = Table1.IdT1 AND IdT1Group = 30)
    MERGE INTO Table2 AS tblTarget
    USING (SELECT @T2.*, T1Item.IdT1 AS T1Id FROM @T2 CROSS JOIN Table1 where IdT1Group = 30)
            AS tblSource
        ON tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET Detail = tblSource.Detail
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            
    INSERT (IdItem, IdT2, Detail)
    VALUES (tblSource.IdT1,
            tblSource.IdT2, tblSource.Detail);
```

But after i tried my code, my table2 become:

```
IdT2 : 1,2,5, 6,7,8, 9,10,11

IdT1 : 11,11,11, 12,12,12, 13,13,13

Detail: A,B,C, A,B,C, A,B,C
```

This is what should it be:

```
IdT2 : 1,2,5, 3,4,6, 7,8,9

IdT1 : 11,11,11, 12,12,12, 13,13,13

Detail : A,B,C, A,B,C, A,B,C
```

Comment: Please take some time and reformat your sample data/tables.

Comment: Your descriptions of your tables and data is very confusing.   And I have no idea why you would expect to get what you are expecting from a merge.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output should look like follows because one of the values get deleted. further i think you have a identity column or a incremental value in the Table2 for IdT2. 
when you delete an item the increased value will not get deducted.

output

```
        IdT2        IdT1        Detail
        ----------- ----------- -------
        1           11          A
        2           11          B
        5           11          C
        3           12          C
        6           12          A
        7           12          B
        8           13          A
        9           13          B
        10          13          C
```

SQL statement (NOTE: Created # tables instead of physical tables to get this going)

```
    create table #Table1
    (
    IdT1    int , IdT1Group int
    )

    insert into #Table1
    select 11 IdT1,30  IdT1Group union all
    select 12 IdT1,30  IdT1Group union all
    select 13 IdT1,30  IdT1Group

    create table #Table2
    (
    IdT2 int identity(1,1),   IdT1     int , Detail varchar(100)
    )

    insert into #Table2
    SELECT   11 IdT1 ,'A' Detail union all
    SELECT   11 ,'B'      union all
    SELECT   12 ,'A'      union all
    SELECT   12 ,'B'

    declare @T2  table  
    (
    IdT2 int ,   IdT1     int , Detail varchar(100)
    )

    insert into @T2
    SELECT 1 IdT2 ,  11 IdT1 ,'A' Detail union all
    SELECT 2 ,  11 ,'B' union all
    SELECT 3 ,  12 ,'C'

    MERGE INTO #Table2 AS tblTarget
    USING (SELECT T2.*, T1Item.IdT1 AS T1Id FROM @T2 T2 CROSS JOIN #Table1 T1Item where IdT1Group = 30)
            AS tblSource
        ON  tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id   And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2--tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
        SET Detail = tblSource.Detail
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            
        INSERT (IdT1,  Detail)
        VALUES (tblSource.T1Id,
                 tblSource.Detail);

    select * from #Table2
    order by 2,1

    drop table #Table1
    drop table #Table2
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggesting, i'll try it now